# KnockoutJS click binding does not work as expected

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I have the following code (shell is global to my application and is not in my viewmodel):

```
<div data-bind="if: shell.metadata().User().IsRootUser()" class="up-one-level text-center">
        <a data-bind="click: shell.navigateToLandingPage" class="btn btn-admin">@Global.BackToAdmin</a>
</div>
```

Access to shell.metadata() works fine in the if data-bind, but in the click data-bind, I got a null value for shell. I also tried some variants like

```
    <div data-bind="if: shell.metadata().User().IsRootUser()" class="up-one-level text-center">
        <a data-bind="click: function() { shell.navigateToLandingPage() }" class="btn btn-admin">@Global.BackToAdmin</a>
</div>
```

I read on the Knockout.js web site that we need to be careful with the meaning of "this" because it changes depending of the context. Looks like it is related to my problem, but I have no idea how to fix it (I don't want to expose a method in my new method to access shell from there).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the shell.navigateToLandingPage method, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `shell` is assumed to be a property on the current Knockout context (on your view model). If you want to use a global variable in data-bindings it's probably best to be explicit, like such:

```js
// Mocking mentioned global variable
window.shell = {
    metadata: function() {
        return {
            User: function() {
                return {
                    IsRootUser: function() { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    navigateToLandingPage: function() {
        alert('navigating!');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="if: window.shell.metadata().User().IsRootUser()" class="up-one-level text-center">
    <a data-bind="click: window.shell.navigateToLandingPage">@Global.BackToAdmin</a>
</div>
```

All this assumes that you're running in the context of a browser with the `window` being defined.

Alternatively, you can wrap the data-bound things in a function, like so:

```js
// Mocking global
window.shell = {
    metadata: function() {
        return {
            User: function() {
                return {
                    IsRootUser: function() { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    navigateToLandingPage: function() {
        alert('navigating!');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="if: function() { return shell.metadata().User().IsRootUser(); }">
    <a data-bind="click: function() { shell.navigateToLandingPage($data); }">@Global.BackToAdmin</a>
</div>
```